# iptables NAT forward range

Tags: iptables, nat, ipv4, dnat

I have two network interfaces, eth0 and eth1. eth0 has a public ip, eth1 has 172.16.0.254/24.

I'd like to do the following mapping:

```
172.16.0.1:22 -> eth0's public ip:2001
172.16.0.2:22 -> eth0's public ip:2002
172.16.0.3:22 -> eth0's public ip:2003 
...
172.16.0.100:22 -> eth0's public ip:2100
```

I read that iptables supports ranges, but I don't get it working.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does ranges have to do with this?

Comment: 172.16.0.[1-100]:22 to public-ip:[2001-2100]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that with iptables natively. You have ip ranges, multiport, but AFAIK you can not map an IP range to a port range.

However this can be solved quite easily with a small bash script :

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 172.16.0.$i --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2`printf "%03d" $i`; done
```

... assuming your server(s) opening 2001-2100 are listening (binded) to all interfaces (0.0.0.0) and you're using TCP.

You might want to use `DNAT` target and `-p udp` respectively if this is not the case.

If having 100 rules in the `PREROUTING` chain is a concern for (readability or maintenance), you can create your own chain instead and jump to it from `PREROUTING`.